# Как красиво отобразить .svg изображение в PyQt5?

Tags: python, svg, pyqt5, gui, barcode

Вот скрипт генерации штрих кода `ean13`. Как отобразить его графическое представление в формате **`.svg`**?

Пока получилось только сохранить в **`.svg`**, а потом загружать содержимое файла, но ***изображение получается искаженное***.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtSvg import QSvgWidget, QSvgRenderer
from PyQt5.QtCore import QXmlStreamReader
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
import barcode


class QSvgWidget_from_string(QSvgWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.text = open('ean13.svg', 'r')
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        
        svg_render = QSvgRenderer(QXmlStreamReader(self.text.read()))
        qp.restore()
        svg_render.render(qp)
        qp.end()
    

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
svgWidget = QSvgWidget_from_string()
svgWidget.setGeometry(300,300,600,600)
svgWidget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**P.S.** сам штрих код генерируется в другом скрипте:

```
import sys
import os
import barcode

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class BarcodeGenerate(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('barcode_design.ui', self)
        self.btnGenerate.clicked.connect(self.generate)
        self.show()
    
    def generate(self):
        self.eanNum = self.editNum.text()
        self.ean13 = barcode.get('ean13', self.eanNum)
        self.ean13_svg = self.ean13.save('ean13')
        self.viewBarcode = self.ean13_svg
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = BarcodeGenerate()
    #window.main()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 4):

Видимо штрих код генерируется как-то не корректно.

Я немного упорядочил ваш код и он у меня работает правильно. Попробуйте.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtSvg import QSvgWidget, QSvgRenderer
from PyQt5.QtCore import QXmlStreamReader
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
#import barcode


class QSvgWidget_from_string(QSvgWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        text = open('demo2.svg', 'r')                                        # <--- demo2.svg                               
        self.svg_render = QSvgRenderer(QXmlStreamReader(text.read()))        
        
        # Возвращает размер содержимого документа по умолчанию.
        size = self.svg_render.defaultSize()
        print(f'size = {size}')
        self.resize(size)                                                    # +++
        
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        self.svg_render.render(qp)
    

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    svgWidget = QSvgWidget_from_string()
# -    svgWidget.setGeometry(300,300,600,600)                                # ---
    svgWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**demo2.svg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="500" width="500">
  <line x1="100" y1="50" x2="100" y2="450" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  <line x1="400" y1="50" x2="400" y2="450" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  <line x1="100" y1="100" x2="400" y2="100" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:20" />
  <line x1="100" y1="200" x2="125" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(0,255,0);stroke-width:20" />
  <line x1="200" y1="300" x2="300" y2="300" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:20" />
  <line x1="300" y1="400" x2="400" y2="400" style="stroke:rgb(127,127,127);stroke-width:20" />
</svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @TUfeed13 что не так ?